# VB + find file under current dir with fso.FileExists

Tags: vbscript

what’s wrong on the following syntax
I want to verify if file.vb exist under currDir (currDir=C:\dir1\dir2)

If (fso.FileExists(currDir\file.vb)) Then

Wscript.Echo OK

End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing double quotes and concatenation operator `&`:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
currDir="C:\dir1\dir2"

If (fso.FileExists(currDir & "\file.vb")) Then
  Wscript.Echo OK
End If
```